# Is it possible to create a kind of horizontal "invert mask" in CSS?

Tags: color, css, mask

I have two blocks (div elements) with one black on the top `background-color: black` and one white on the bottom.

**Is it possible to have a piece of text that straddles the two zones with inverted colors?**

For example: the top part of the text "FOO" will be white on black and the bottom part black over a white region.

Comment: Related and useful: [Is it possible to apply CSS to half of a character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character) and one of the best answers to the q as a plugin: [Splitchar](http://emisfera.github.io/Splitchar.js/) - this plugin also does what is asked for on this page, yet it can also do **3** levels of colour horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

[image]

---

**Edit:** here's a way which only requires one HTML element and so won't be weird when read by non-CSS-styling clients like search engines, screen readers, RSS, 'no style' apps etc (thanks to Dominic for suggesting trying `:before` and `:after`).

### http://jsbin.com/UtUlIFO/2/edit

The important code (**add your colours to this**):

HTML: `<div class="someclass" data-text="Some text">Some text</div>`

CSS:

```
.someclass {     /* bottom half */
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.someclass:after {     /* top half */
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The HTML attribute can be anything - I used [`data-text`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) because it's descriptive and avoids undesirable side effects (e.g. you could use `title` but it would create mouseovers in some browsers).

If you want `display:block;` on the main (`.top`) element, add something like `width: 100%;` to the inner (`.bottom`) element so it fills it.

If you're using jQuery, you can apply this style to any element really easily, avoiding having to manually type out the `data-text` duplicated bit:

```
$('.someElement').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('someclass').attr('data-text',$(this).text());
});
```

### [Demo of that plus some other stuff like multiple lines, padding](http://jsbin.com/UtUlIFO/4/edit)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do it by creating the duplicate text with a pseudo-element (`:after` or `:before`) any ideas?

Comment: Interesting idea: you can do [this (duplicating the content hard-coded into the CSS)](http://jsbin.com/UtUlIFO/3/edit) or [this (duplicating the content in a HTML attribute, then reading that)](http://jsbin.com/UtUlIFO/2/edit) but [apparently it's not possible to simply read the HTML content text using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175113/content-attribute-to-inherit-node-value). The HTML attribute way seems the best since it doesn't mess up machine-reading of the HTML. I've added some things like this above.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, it is possible, though I'd only advise it if you're website is **all** about the visual impact and the semantics of the code don't matter, additionally it probably won't be very consistent across older browsers.

The result is:

[image: Inverted Text]

This is not a pretty solution, and I'd bet it's not the only one out there, but it does what you want.

It requires that you have two instances of the text, and using absolute positioning and some simple maths, you can create this effect.

So if we have a container `div`, and within that two more `divs`, and within each of those an instance of the text, you can use the following `HTML` structure and `CSS` properties to achieve this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="black">
       <div class="text">Invert</div>
    </div>
    <div class="white">
       <div class="text">Invert</div>
    </div>
</div>

.container{position:relative; width:200px; height:100px; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px; }

.black, .white{position:absolute; left:0px; background:#000; width:200px; height:50px; margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; }

.black{top:0px; }

.white{bottom:0px; background:#fff; }

.text{position:absolute; color:#fff; font-size:70px; padding:0px; }

.black .text{bottom:-40px; }

.white .text{top:-40px; color:#000; }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/domwebdev/kdXzz/1/) of the result. :)

Comment: Oooh posted while I was finishing typing! Nice answer but I think there's a couple of ways it can be simplified to be more something that can be dropped in anywhere. I think there's no way to do it without duplicating text.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a **CSS3 property**, only supported by webkit, that inverts colors:

```
image {
 -webkit-filter: invert(100%);  
}
```

And there's an **HTML5 Canvas Invert**, [here's an example and the full code](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/). It iterates over all of the pixels in an image and inverts red, green, and blue by subtracting each component from the max color value, 255.

Both solutions would still require 2 images and CSS positioning for them. Since compatibility is not very good, I'd definitely go for one of the other answers :)